# MySQL INSERT ... SELECT with aggregated value fails with Case not found for CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I would like to insert a new row into my table from the output of an aggregated query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id) SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM table_name;
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 1339 (20000): Case not found for CASE statement
```

If I add the `+ 1` part to the aggregate function like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id) SELECT MAX(id + 1) FROM table_name;
```

it produces the same error. If I remove the `+ 1` part, it will of course fail because the `id` is the primary key:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '48' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How can I achieve this in MySQL 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 without modifying the table structure?

#### UPDATE

This is probably because of a missing not null field in the original table, I'll post the solution here if I'll find it out tomorrow.

Comment: Your first query works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95ee7/1

Comment: Hopefully you aren't building a makeshift auto_increment with this...

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, because it [works fine for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbe9a/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the error said differently the cause of the problem was a missing not NULL field in the insert.

Filling out every field resulted a correct `MAX(id) + 1` query.

Answer (score 2):

since you want to increment the last id by one, why don't you use `AUTO_INCREMENT` column for column `ID`.

```
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
)
```

Comment: Please revise your answer, because I don't have the permission to modify my table.

Comment: @KARASZIIstván Manually incrementing the value can never work reliably (except in isolated usage) in any environment where multiple requests are made to the database from multiple clients. It will be subject to race conditions. This is the purpose of the AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I know that, but this was not the question.